# I am Exporting CSV using a method call flash successful but I am getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

customers_controller.rb

```
  def export
@customers =Customer.all

flash[:success] = "Script ran successfully"
end
```

What does it mean when the error message say syntax error, unexpected keyword_do, expecting keyword_end flash[:success] = "Script ran successfully" do |format| ^.
I am trying to export a cvs file from my database using a flash success method. I look at rails cast but it could not help me with this problem
index.html.erb

```
 <p><%= button_to 'export Import', scripts_export_data_path %></p>
```

Comment: The error makes it clear what the problem is. Read it.

Comment: This question should be closed because the edit #2 completely changes what the question was.

Answer (score 0):

Check you syntax and read your error (as Zabba mentioned from the comments). You will want something similar to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv { render text: @customers.to_csv }
  flash[:success] = "Script ran successfully"
end
```

Notice how there is an `end` with the  `respond_to`  block. Make sure to read your error messages as they are pretty useful.

Comment: I fix the above error message but when I add the code that you have it get a different error message: ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: That should be for a separate question. You changed the questions context in which was answered.